# Adding three hours to a date field in a blade

Tags: php, laravel

The following is the date column and it's vardump :

```
<td>{{$words['return_dt'] }}</td>
```

```
2019-11-25 10:08:55
```

How can I add three hours to this so that the output would be :

```
2019-11-25 01:08:55
```

Comment: you can do this via `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($words["return_dt"]." +3 hours"))`

Comment: Is `$words` an Eloquent model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this via

```
{{ date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($words["return_dt"]." +3 hours")) }}
```

and output will become

> 2019-11-25 13:08:55

If you need `2019-11-25 01:08:55` then you have to minus 9 Hours.

Answer (score 4):

For Datetime laravel use Carbon facade. You simply use `addHours()`.

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse( $words['return_dt'] )->addHours(3) }}
```

Comment: If you have used laravel then the `carbon`  facade is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

If you use twig you can try this:

```
{{ $words['return_dt']|date_modify("+3 hours")|date("Y-m-d H:i:s") }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best solution,first convert int timestamp and add 3 hours and convert into your format.

```
<td>{{ date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($words["return_dt"]." +3 hours")) }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default laravel comes with the Carbon Library

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse( $words['return_dt'] )->add("3 Hour") }}
```

And you are not just limited to add only hours

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse( $words['return_dt'] )->add("5 days 3 Hours 25 Minutes") }}
```

is Equivalent To

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse( $words['return_dt'] )->addDays(5)->addHours(3)->addMinutes(25) }}
```